# Servo Motor Control

Tags: pwm, servo

I tried to control servo motor by using servo library in Arduino and it is working fine. But when I use separate power supply and function generator, it is not working. It is go to end which means 180 degree.

I used SG90 servo motor. Separate power supply voltage is 5V like arduino. I used PWM 50Hz in Function generator and duty cycle 3%. If I set 1% duty cycle,  it is also going to end. PWM peak voltage is 5V.

Comment: Did you remember to connect the Arduino ground and the ground to the servo power supply?

Comment: Fist I used ardunio but second time I used separate power supply and function generator.

Comment: The ground of whatever generates the PWM signal and the ground of the servo MUST be connected together.

Comment: Do you have your function generator grounded to the Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

You better check your math. 1~2ms /  20ms is 5~10% not 1%

[image]